# A different way to receive output from OpenSSL in ANSI C

Tags: c, pointers, openssl, exec

This is for a homework assignment so I won't be sharing my code.  I'm only allowed to have "pencil down" discussions.  I think that's what he called it, so basically just a discussion. I'm not looking for code experts.

In my program, I fork multiple times and execlp openssl with dgst which returns a MD5 hash(?).  I'm using this string to compare multiple files to see if they are identical.

Currently, the only way I have found to get the output from this is to use -out and save it to a file, but doing this over and over doesn't append the file, it just rewrites the file so doing this is kind of a slow, painful process.

I'm asking if there is a way through exec or openssl that I can write this output string to a pointer that the parent could then access and manipulate from there so I am not writing to a file and reading it via the parent, one process at a time.

Comment: Right now Im looking into making a Fifo pipe and some how have openssl output to the pipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you `fork`, you can use `pipe` to create a pair of unidirectional file descriptors (one for reading, and one for writing). After you `fork`, you can use `dup2` to set the writing end of the pipe for that child process to the output file descriptor and then `exec`. Then, when the parent reads from the reading end of the pipe, it will be reading what the child process is writing to its `stdout`.

Since you are comparing output from multiple children processes, each child should have it's own pipe.

```
int fd[2];
pipe(fd);
pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) {
    close(fd[0]);
    dup2(fd[1], 1);
    execlp(/*...*/);
} else if (pid > 0) {
    close(fd[1]);
    while (read(fd[0], /*...*/) > 0) {
        /* ... */
    }
    wait4(&pid, /*...*/);
}
/* ... */
```

This is just a mock-up of the calls you need to use. Your code will have to deal with reading from multiple pipes.

Comment: Thanks Ill look into dup2 

then I would up vote for the quick response but I need more rep for it so if someone reads this can you throw him an upvote

Comment: I got something super basic working I should be able to figure the rest out Thank you so much!